# template class with overridden operators

Tags: c++, templates, operators

I want to add a operator override to perform **assignments**/__set__s inline.

Template :-

```
class CBase {
    public :
        static void SetupVmeInterface(CVmeInterface *in);

    protected :
        static CVmeInterface *pVmeInterface;
};


template <class T> class TCVmeAccess : public CBase {
    public:
        TCVmeAccess(int address);

        T get()
        {
            unsigned long temp = pVmeInterface->ReadAddress(Address);
            T ret = *reinterpret_cast<T*>(&temp);
            return ret;
        };

        T *operator->();
        unsigned long asLong();

        bool set(T data)
        {
            unsigned long write_data = *reinterpret_cast<unsigned long*>(&data);
            return pVmeInterface->WriteAddress(Address, write_data);
        };

        // void operator->(T);
        void operator=(T data)
        { set(data); }

    private :
        int Address;
};
```

A struct that will be used in the template :-

```
typedef struct
{
    int a: 1; // 0
    int b: 1; // 1
    int c: 1; // 2
    int d: 1; // 3
    int NotUsed : 28; // 31-4
} _HVPSUControl;
```

Code body :-

```
TCVmeAccess<_HVPSUControl> HVPSUControl(constHVPSUControlBlock);
_HVPSUControl hvpsu = HVPSUControl.get(); // Yep, good, but not as nice as...
int a = HVPSUControl2.get().OperationalRequestPort; // yep, also good, but...
int b = HVPSUControl->a; // works, and is all go so far

HVPSUControl.set(hvpsu); // works, but need _HVPSUControl type
HVPSUControl = hvpsu;    // also works, as operator = is used, but still need type

// this line does not work!
// as the = assignment is redirected into a copy of the struct, not the template
HVPSUControl->a = 1; // this line
```

So, is there a way to get *this line* above to work?

Edit: 
As in, I want "this line" to perform as a "set" as does in the template class.

Edit:
1. Assign a value directly in-line to a member of the struct that the template is formed 
of.
2. Cause that assignment to go though a template accessor.

So that I dont have to do this on assignments :-

```
// HVPSUControl is predefined and used many times.
_HVPSUControl hvpsu;
hvpsu.a = 1;
HVPSUControl.set(hvpsu);
```

I want to do

```
HVPSUControl.a = 1; // or 
HVPSUControl->a = 1; // or ?
```

As gets work on line :

if (HVPSUControl->a)

Comment: What is your desired behaviour?

Comment: What do you actually want to do and why does the error surprise you

Comment: I want "this line" to perform as a "set" does in the template class.

Comment: BTW, there is "no error" as such, it just doesnt "do anything" (it doesnt go via the template =)

Comment: It seems to me that `operator->` is returning a T*, then there is just an `a` there.  The `a` is probably being compiled as an argument to `operator->`, But I don't understand how you would be able to use that because it's not really a variable or anything.

Comment: @Dave, your correct, and its why Im asking for ideas on this. I need the assignment to go though a method call.

Comment: To let your code perform "set" method, I think you need to put a struct object as lvalue, like this:
  HVPSUControl = hvpsu;

Comment: @Steve, yes that works (see my line "// also works, as operator...", but I want to extract from the template the type info, and then call a set method within the template on my assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of overwriting the "->" and the "=" operator, you could derive from the template struct.

```
template <class T> class TCVmeAccess : public CBase, public T {
    public:
        TCVmeAccess(int address);

        T get();
        // T *operator->();
        unsigned long asLong();

        bool set(T);
        // void operator->(T);
        // void operator=(T);

    private :
        int Address;
};

HVPSUControl.a = 1; // and use this for setting a bitfield.
```

Edit: If you want to use an custom assignment operator, you should declare it in HVPSUControl, or a even a base class of it, if you have more of this control-like structures.

```
struct _HVPSUControl
{
    int a: 1; // 0
    int b: 1; // 1
    int c: 1; // 2
    int d: 1; // 3
    int NotUsed : 28; // 31-4
    void operator = (int x);
};
```

or

```
struct _HVPSUBase {
    void operator = (int x);
}
struct _HVPSUControl: public _HVPSUBase
{
    int a: 1; // 0
    int b: 1; // 1
    int c: 1; // 2
    int d: 1; // 3
    int NotUsed : 28; // 31-4
};
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it will assign "1" locally to the instance of "HVPSUControl", whereas I need that assignment to go though an accessor method in my class (i need to do some processing on it)

Comment: Ah, just read the ", public T" in the "dervied" part of your text..., will play...

Comment: Nope, it will just set the local instance of the struct. I need an assignment to go through an accessor in the template class.

Comment: Close, although its a shame to have to derive all my (40+) structs from a base struct, it would be a small price to pay to save the inline code... if it would work!             

I will play with it...

Comment: the assignment doesnt know which struct member has been assigned a value.  I think what I want cannot be done!

Comment: With your idea of deriving the template class from the struct ": public CBase, public T {"... If the template class could have an operator overridden then that would be used when accessing struct members? Cant override ".", but maybe an odd char. "void operator~(int x); .... inline "HVPSUControl~a = 1;"??

Answer (score 0):

You can't get this line to work any other way. You call `TCVmeAccess::operator->` which returns a `_HVPSUControl*` and then you access `_HVPSUControl*::a`.

Or do you want to assign integer 1 to the complete `_HVPSUControl` struct?

```
template <class T> class TCVmeAccess : public CBase {
public:
    // ...

    void operator=(T data) { set(data); }
    void operator=(int n) { operator=(T(n)); }

    // ...
};


typedef struct
{
    _HVPSUControl(int n) {
       *this = reinterpret_cast<_HVPSUControl>(n);
    }

    int a: 1; // 0
    int b: 1; // 1
    int c: 1; // 2
    int d: 1; // 3
    int NotUsed : 28; // 31-4
} _HVPSUControl;
```

and then do

```
HVPSUControl = 1;
```

Comment: Quick reply on "do I want to assign integer 1 to all" = nope!

I want to extract the struct member from the template, assign some data to it. But that assignment needs to go though the template class so I can do stuff with it.